# Kivy Buildozer Permission Denied on ./distribute.sh -1

Tags: android, python, kivy

Ok so first before anything let me show the error

```
# Android packages installation done.
# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /media/jonathon/Data Volume/Python Projects/Kivy Tutorial/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
/bin/sh: 1: ./distribute.sh: Permission denied
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -l
```

The command I am running is `sudo buildozer android debug` so I know I am running sudo and have root permissions.

Comment: Please don't run buildozer as root. Could you delete your .buildozer directory (including the one in your user dir if that was created as root) and run again as a normal user?

Comment: Ok I seemed to get past that issue but now I ran into '# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"' There was no other error or anything to tell me what caused it. The only lines before it was Check garden requirements and Compile platform

Comment: why shouldn't you run buildozer as root can you explain @inclement ?

Comment: 1) For the same reason you shouldn't run anything else as root, and 2) because it will litter root-owned files around your home dir which causes problems later both when you want to manipulate them yourself and when (potentially) other parts of the android build tools try to access them without having root permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the file path in your error, you may be using a shared drive or remote file system. These can cause problems with permissions when buildozer tries to run and compile things. Try deleting ~/.buildozer, the .buildozer dir in your project, then moving the files to a local hard drive and running buildozer without sudo.

Comment: Ok I seemed to get past that issue but now I ran into

'# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"'

There was no other error or anything to tell me what caused it. The only lines before it was Check garden requirements and Compile platform

Comment: Run it again with --verbose, like: buildozer --verbose android debug

Comment: cp: cannot copy a directory, ‘/home/jonathon’, into itself, ‘Tutorial/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/jonathon’
cp: cannot stat ‘Tutorial/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/blacklist.txt’: No such file or directory
cp: will not create hard link ‘Tutorial/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/jonathon’ to directory ‘Tutorial/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/jonathon’
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"

Comment: Looks like a path issue. Post your buildozer.spec

Comment: Can you try it on a path with no spaces?